# MySQL - how to select all data with 1 condition and complete if necessary with other condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, asp-classic

I Have a DB with a STATUS column and 3 conditions:

**-1 = REPROVED

0 = NEUTRO

1 = APPROVED**

I need to divid all registers in 2 sets:

SET 1 (MAIN) - This is the "MAIN" table and have a limit of 5 registers. But ALL APPROVED must be in this table - even if we have more than 5 - and NONE "REPROVED" register can be here.

for example:
- If we have 10 APPROVED - the main Table will have 10 ALL APPROVED.
- If we have 2 APPROVED - the main Table will have 2 ALL APPROVED + 3 NEUTROS. (5 TOTAL) - But if I have only 1 Neutros and 10 REPPROVED for example - the table will have 2 ALL APPROVED + 1 NEUTROS only. (3 registers).

SET 2 - Will have ALL REPROVED + the rest of NEUTROS - without limit of registers.

Situation 1: MORE STATUS 1 THAN THE REGISTER LIMIT (5)

```
ID - NAME - STATUS
1 - John  -  1
2 - Mary  -  1
3 - Mike  -  1
4 - James -  1
5 - Helen -  1
6 - Fred  -  1
7 - Nick  -  1
8 - Gio   -  0
9 - Rick  -  0
10 - May  - -1
```

SET 1 will be: (ALL STATUS 1)

```
ID - NAME - STATUS
1 - John  -  1
2 - Mary  -  1
3 - Mike  -  1
4 - James -  1
5 - Helen -  1
6 - Fred  -  1
7 - Nick  -  1
```

SET 2 will be:

```
8 - Gio   -  0
9 - Rick  -  0
10 - May  - -1
```

situation 2: (COMPLETE THE TABLE WITH STATUS 0)

```
ID - NAME - STATUS
1 - John  -  1
2 - Mary  -  1
3 - Mike  -  1
4 - James -  0
5 - Helen -  0
6 - Fred  -  0
7 - Nick  -  0
8 - Gio   -  0
9 - Rick  -  0
10 - May  - -1
```

SET 1 will be: (ALL STATUS 1 + 2 WITH STATUS 0)

```
ID - NAME - STATUS
1 - John  -  1
2 - Mary  -  1
3 - Mike  -  1
4 - James -  0
5 - Helen -  0
```

SET 2 will be:

```
6 - Fred  -  0
7 - Nick  -  0
8 - Gio   -  0
9 - Rick  -  0
10 - May  - -1
```

and then - situation 3: (ALL STATUS 1 + STATUS 0 Less than the register limit - 5)

```
ID - NAME - STATUS
1 - John  -  1
2 - Mary  -  1
3 - Mike  -  1
4 - James -  0
5 - Helen - -1
6 - Fred  - -1
7 - Nick  - -1
8 - Gio   - -1
9 - Rick  - -1
10 - May  - -1
```

SET 1 will be: (ALL STATUS 1 + 1 WITH STATUS 0 - only 4 registers)

```
ID - NAME - STATUS
1 - John  -  1
2 - Mary  -  1
3 - Mike  -  1
4 - James -  0
```

SET 2 will be:

```
5 - Helen - -1
6 - Fred  - -1
7 - Nick  - -1
8 - Gio   - -1
9 - Rick  - -1
10 - May  - -1
```

any idea?

Comment: You seem to be confusing the terms DB and TABLE. By DB, I presume you mean table, and by table I presume you are talking about the result of a query. I'm sure we have lots of ideas, but you need to show what you have tried. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Hello @SloanThrasher first of all tks for your precious time to help me. I'm not an expert in mysql - but I guess that will be a better solution with mysql. I'm trying a solution with Classic ASP - using DO/LOOP but I cannot limit the table as I need

Comment: You need to use prepare statements to make your query dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

The normal approach will be to gather the rows to be displayed using a SQL query. 
That will provide the selection (WHERE clause) and sorting (ORDER BY clause). Once 
you have the rows, use ASP to render the HTML as needed.

I'll leave the ASP-classic to you.

**First 5 with status = 1**

```
SELECT 
    `id`,
    `name`,
    `status`
FROM `table`
WHERE `status` = 1
ORDER BY `status` DESC,`name` ASC
LIMIT 5;
```

**All with status of 1 or 0**

```
SELECT 
    `id`,
    `name`,
    `status`
FROM `table`
WHERE `status` IN (0,1)
ORDER BY `status` DESC,`name` ASC;
```

**All with status of -1**

```
SELECT 
    `id`,
    `name`,
    `status`
FROM `table`
WHERE `status` = -1
ORDER BY `status` DESC,`name` ASC;
```

Comment: Which one? The first one limits the results to the first 5

Comment: If you want to limit the 2nd one, add a limit clause.

Comment: If 7 users are approved, the first set is to include 7 items and not the default limit of 5